# Pushing Zero's to the end of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a code wars problem where I'm tasked with moving all zero's to the end of an array without moving the position of any other elements in said array. I'm looping through the array, identifying if a 0 is found, then splicing it out of the array while adding a 0 to a second array. At the end of the function I concat the two arrays and return that.

```
var moveZeros = function (arr) {
  // TODO: Program me
  var Zeros = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] === 0){
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      Zeros.push(0);
    }
  }

  return arr.concat(Zeros);

  //loop through arr
    //if arr[i] is 0
      //take out of arr and push into newarr

  //return arr + newarr
}
```

For the test cases where I know what the inputs are I pass. However I'm failing three test cases:

```
Expected: '[9,9,1,2,1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]', instead got: '[9,0,9,1,2,1,1,3,1,9,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]'
Expected: '["a","b","c","d",1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]', instead got: '["a",0,"b","c","d",1,1,3,1,9,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]'
Expected: '["a","b",null,"c","d",1,false,1,3,[],1,9,{},9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]', instead got: '["a",0,"b",null,"c","d",1,false,1,3,[],1,9,0,{},0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]'
```

As you can see they show me the expected output but not the inputs, as such I have no way of debugging my problem. Can someone give me some insight as to where I went wrong/what I'm missing?

Comment: not a good idea splicing inside `for` loop

Comment: Very true, if you are going to splice inside a for loop you would want to decrement from the end of the array to the beginning, so the index you are changing does not get changed out from under you.

Comment: [Related kata link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/moving-zeros-to-the-end/javascript), here is an alternative: `return arr.filter(x => x !== 0).concat(arr.filter(x => x === 0));` - sad kata... very few static tests, no random tests, completely overrated.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Could you explain whats going on in your function chain? you're filtering out 0's then concatenating it with another array that filters out non zero's correct?

Comment: Yes, `filter` will keep the original order, so i concatenate all non-zero elements with all zero elements. This iterates twice, but for this case, i didn't care about that.